# Prevent *minor* leak from kitchen faucet base

Tags: faucet, mold

I noticed a small amount of mold (or mildew) on the dry wall under my kitchen sink.  I don't know how long it's been there, or how long it's taken it to get there, but I cleaned it up with some disinfecting clorox wipes.  Is it possible some tiny amount of water go through the part where my faucet meets the counter top?  If so, is there anything I can put there to stop it?  See photo.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: yes, that's certainly possible. Recaulk it by loosening the faucet, apply caulk under, re-attach, then trim off the excess.

Comment: @dandavis: excellent, I can definitely handle that. What kind of caulk would you recommend? Anything clear?

Comment: just about anything will work. i like clear 100% silicone for inside water-tight jobs. there should be a giant plastic nut that will release your faucet without affecting water connections.

Comment: @dandavis: sounds good, thanks again

Comment: 100% silicone, Kitchen and Bath, **Mold and Mildew resistant** caulk.

Comment: Is your little back splash and sink one piece? If not, you might want to cualk that too.

Comment: @JACK great eye, didn't even think about that. it doesn't look like it's one piece. I can feel caulk there already, but I guess no harm in adding a little more.

Comment: Well, that's not exactly true. More caulk will look sloppy, but more importantly _silicone doesn't stick to silicone_. It won't bond well.

Comment: @isherwood did not know that!

Comment: You want to remove the old caulk, clean the area and run a very small bead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caulk may work to some extent, but silicone is soft and doesn't withstand movement terribly well. I'd check whether there's a seal missing at that location. Maybe it was installed in the wrong position.

If not, I'd install a thin rubber or silicone washer. This would mean disconnecting the faucet supply lines and removing the mounting nut, but it will result in a more reliable seal than caulk.

Otherwise, definitely use pure silicone caulk and not latex, which won't bond as well and tends to harden over time, which will result in cracking and failure.